# Catch crash of 3rd party exe with Python without WinAppDbg

Tags: python, debugging, crash, detection

Need to launch 3rd party exe with command line and check whether it has crashed.

I've done this by using [WinAppDbg](http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/), but sometimes Python interpreter crashes because of it (doesnt even spit anything to console), so I'm looking for another approach.

Looked at subprocess module, but it seems I can't achieve what I want with it.

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me a bit more about the WinAppDbg crash?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of alternatives to WinAppDbg, you can find them in the webpage. My personal favorite is vtrace. http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/#related-projects

Answer (score -1):

This is not elegant, but does the deal - spotting DWWIN.EXE in process list means you had the crash.

Comment: It could also mean that something else crashed or someone compiled an executable named dwwin.exe. Not very reliable...